# rmarkdown to pdf: image in headers x margin

Tags: pdf, rstudio, r-markdown

I am new to markdown and want to produce pdf files with the university (and other) logo on each page. I tried to use fancyheadings, and I have a problem:

Putting the image in the headings works only if I call the image in the document, otherwise the pdf is not produced

NB: I also had to set the heading height otherwise the page 2 would not work with - \setlength{\headheight}{2.4 cm}.

Any suggestions were the problem is?
(using knit in Rstudio, all freshly installed)

```
    ---
title: "Test"
author: "Author Name"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \rhead {\includegraphics{pictures/headers.pdf}}
- \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{}
- \setlength{\headheight}{2.4 cm}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
geometry: top=2cm, bottom=3cm
output: pdf_document
abstract: This is a pandoc test . . .
---

\lipsum[1-20]
![](./pictures/headers.pdf)
this line needed or it doesnot make an output ???

\cleardoublepage
This is an R Markdown document.
```

Comment: getting this piece of code instead of the picture also make it work:
     ```{r, echo=FALSE}
     plot(cars)
     ```

Answer (score 0):

the includegraphics works only if there is a picture in the document, maybe because of the latex template (?).

A solution is to create a cache picture (1white pixel picture) and call it at the end of the code: